# Side of Vanity Underneath has separated From the Rear

Tags: woodworking, plywood, vanity

Underneath our vanity, the back portion has separated from the right side causing the drawer to come apart as well. The wall is too far back to connect it to anything. I feel like there has to be something that can just jerry rig it for a rough and cheap repair. My concern is I'm going to have to redo the whole vanity, which we can't afford. I've attached photos which should provide a better explanation.

[image: Bottom Right top Corner of Vanity]

[image: Bottom right top corner of vanity]

[image: Bottom right top Corner of Vanity]

Comment: I would want to dismount the cabinet to repair it. How deeply lodged in place is it?

Comment: Also, what is on the right side—is there a wall, or do you have access to the exterior of that side of the cabinet?  Is it the side that has separated from the back, or the back that has separated from the side?

Answer (score 2):

It's either poor quality, or badly stressed by not sitting on the floor properly to support it, or both. You should look for and address improper floor support to have the repair attempt last.

I suppose if you wanted to bodge a steel angle bracket in there that might make a crude fix, but how well screws will hold in whatever sort of not-quite-wood it's apparently made from is unknown.

[image: Angle brackets]

*[Image Source](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fimages-na.ssl-images-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FI%2F51kWmeH40TL._AC_US1000_.jpg&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=6f49e866993cbfa11a9d874efe29f7a195ae1ebf963ae983e1a17f73776da9e1&ipo=images) no endorsement*